# How to I determine whether an ASCII representation of integer is negative or positive

Tags: mips

Here is an example:
given the number -4, which is 0xFFFFFFFF in hex.
I need to somehow get the first F (1111), then AND it with 8
If the result is greater or equal to 8, then it is negative.

```
    1111
AND 1000
 ----------
    1000
```

I have no idea how to get the first F (1111).

Comment: -4 is 0xFFFFFFFC, not 0xFFFFFFFF. Anyway, I don't understand how ASCII representation comes into play here. You've got a string containing a bunch of digits..? In what base?

Comment: So  I am given an ASCII representation of integer, I have to somehow determine whether it is negative or positive, then I have to convert it back to integer. The ASCII representation of integer is in hex.

Comment: So read the first character (after the prefix, if there is one) and check if it's `>= '8'`.